# Is Yamori's change of hair color caused by torture?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Yamori (Yakumo Oomori) has undergone torture before. Did the torture really cause Yamori to change his hair color?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the [wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Yakumo_Oomori#Appearance),

> In *Tokyo Ghoul: Jack*, Yamori was slimmer than he was in the *Tokyo Ghoul* manga and had black hair.

In the *Tokyo Ghoul* manga, he already has blonde/white hair. Since he was also subjected to torture similar to Kaneki, and since he was also depicted in the manga standing over his torturer with blonde/white hair, it can be said that the same thing that happened to Kaneki's hair also happened to him. Might also be useful: [Why did Kaneki's hair change color?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14081/why-did-kanekis-hair-change-color?rq=1)